# AppearanceRules on multipage Web Form

Tags: formatting, webservices, format

I'm attempting to make a web survey using `FormFunction`. To list the questions I am using `AppearanceRules` to give each page an individual title. I can't find any documentation in regards to `AppearanceRules` applying to individual pages in a multi-page FormFunction.

This is my sample program:

```
AnswerList1 = {"Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"};

AnswerList1a = {"Yes", "No"};

AnswerList2 = {"Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"};

Question1 = "This is the first Question";

Question1a = 
  "This is a very long second part question to the first question to \
test how it handles long questions";

CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{{ "Question1" -> AnswerList1, 
    "Question1a" -> AnswerList1a}, {"Answer2" -> 
     AnswerList2}},

 {Position[AnswerList1, #Question1], 
    Position[AnswerList1a, #Question1a], 
    Position[AnswerList2, #Answer2]} &, 

  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "This is the first Question", 
    "Description" -> "This is a description"|>

]]
```

This is the first page output

[image]

I have tried to put `AppearanceRules` in a list, and also to have the AppearanceRules in a list of its own.

The second page is complete but with no title, this suggests a way to have a second title for the second page, but I've no idea where to begin on this.

[image]